Use APNS to update Live Activity will not always wake app
I use APNS push notification to start and update Live activity on iOS 17.6
according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/starting-and-updating-live-activities-with-activitykit-push-notifications
I found that the use "start" event type to start a new Live Activity will wake my app when app is not active, so that I can fetch image from the activity.contentUpdates, but when using "update" event type, the live activity will be updated but will not always wake my app(I expect app will call applicationDidFinishingLaunch function)...So the images data in updated content can't be fetched.... I‘m not sure this is expected.
Here is my code
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        self.setupActivityAttr()
        return true
}

private func setupActivityAttr() {
        Task {
            for await data in Activity<T>.pushToStartTokenUpdates {
                let token = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
                // upload start token
            }
        }
        
        Task {
            for await activity in Activity<T>.activityUpdates {
                Task {
                    for await updateContent in activity.contentUpdates {
                        // fetch image from data
                        Task {
                            LiveActivityImageLoader.loadImageFromData(updateContent)
                            await activity.update(updateContent)
                        }
                    }
                }
                // updateToken
                Task {
                    for await tokenData in activity.pushTokenUpdates {
                        let token = tokenData.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }





Did you read the document you linked to? Specifically regarding the update budget and the use of notification priority?  What strategy are you using for your updates?

I use normal update strategy, didn't use any priority... I means the update event reach my device and the Live activity update successfully, but my app does not call applicationDidFinshlaunching function of UIApplicationDelegate.

Is the app terminated? If your app is already running and suspended then didFinishLaunching won't be called because your app is already launched

No, my app is completely not in process and not running.  And not in background.

Why is your app not running? How was it terminated? Normally live activities with updates would be sufficient to keep the app around.

Yes.....When I push a "start" event, the system will wake app can call applicationDidFinshLaunch.  But the update won't ... I dont know why

But why is your app even terminated if it has a live activity running?  It should just be suspended.  If you swiped it away then I am not suprised it is not relaunched

Yes... I swipe it away.......

Then as I said I am not surprised your app is not being relaunched.  If you swipe an app away iOS thinks that you do not want it to run and won't relaunch it until you tap the icon
